# don't allow copy when uitableviewcell is empty

Tags: ios, tableview, copy-paste

I am trying to allow the user to only copy when the tableview cell has value. I am implementing the copy and paste this way:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RightCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //check if the cell is the header of the tableview:
    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[RightCellHeader class]]) {
        return NO;
    }else {
        return YES;
    }

}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(copy:)) {
        return YES;
    }else {
        return NO;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView performAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender
{
    UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

    if (action == @selector(copy:) && pasteboard != nil) {
        RightCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [pasteboard setString:cell.commentLabel.text];

    }

}
```

So!!! what am I missing to only allow the copy menu on **not empty cell**
Tks :)

**NOTE**

When I select copy without selecting a word previously, the app crashes.
image: http://i61.tinypic.com/110zkhv.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **don't allow** in **UITableView delegate** method :

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   //Firstly find cell's text value
   RightCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   NSString *strText = cell.commentLabel.text;
   //Now check if text has got any value
   if(strText.length>0)
      return YES;
   else 
      return NO;
}
```

Comment: Checking the length of the `textField` or the cell did do trick. @Paresh on my scenario I am letting the comment to be done on the footer of the tableview. So I am doing double check `footer` and `cell`.